# Angle between vectors problem

Tags: calculus

[image]

I have this dot product problem here and I have to find the $cos(theta)$ of the dot product. I know the formula is v dot w over norm of v times norm of w but i cant seem to get the answer right...

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've got the right formula, so it sounds like an arithmetic error. You'll have to write out your work if you want someone to find where you went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Recall $\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}=\|\mathbf{u}\|\|\mathbf{v}\|\cos\theta$.

$$
\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}=(-5)(-2)+(1)(-3)+(-1)(-3)=10\\
\\
\|\mathbf{u}\|=\sqrt{(-5)^2+1^2+(-1)^2}=\sqrt{27}\\ \|\mathbf{v}\|=\sqrt{(-2)^2+(-3)^2+(-3)^2}=\sqrt{22}\\
\\
\cos\theta={10\over \sqrt{27}\cdot\sqrt{22}}\approx 0.410305.
$$